# Testing a function which returns an object that returns a function which return a boolean

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a situation where I want to test a function that has been called in an `if` statement. I don't know how to test this function which actually returns a `boolean`.

**Code**

```js
function test(){
  if(await SOP3loginConfig(props: object).isSOP3()){
    //calls if statements
  } else {
    //calls else statements
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, I am trying to test that function, I am able to do that, but can go through the `if()` branch.

I am using `jest` and `react-testing-library`.

I don't have access to the body of the functions within the `if` statements.

**Tried this**

```js
it('Should call the SOP3 functions', () => {
      props.user = {};
      let SOP3loginConfig = (props: any) => {
        console.log(' ========================= I A M A TEST');
        return {
          isSOP3: () => {
            console.log(' ================ iSOP3 called');
            return true;
          },
        };
      };
      functions.start(props);
      expect(SOP3loginConfig(props).isSOP3()).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(props.history.push).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

> But got this error !

```js
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  boolean
    Received has value: true

      229 |       };
      230 |       functions.start(props);
    > 231 |       expect(SOP3loginConfig(props).isSOP3()).toHaveBeenCalled();
          |                                               ^
      232 |       expect(props.history.push).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      233 |     });
      234 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`jest.fn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function)

```js
it('Should call the SOP3 functions', () => {
  props.user = {};
  const isSOP3Mock = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log(' ================ iSOP3 called');
    return true;
  })
  let SOP3loginConfig = (props: any) => {
    console.log(' ========================= I A M A TEST');
    return {
      isSOP3: isSOP3Mock,
    };
  };
  functions.start(props);
  expect(isSOP3Mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(props.history.push).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

assuming the `functions.start(props)` will call your `test` function.

Comment: No Success ! 

`
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      230 |       };
      231 |       functions.start(props);
    > 232 |       expect(isSOP3Mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
          |                          ^
      233 |       expect(props.history.push).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      234 |     });
      235 | 

`

Comment: What is `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()` ? you do not need to call it in the `expect`. You call it before and in the expect check if the variable storing the function has been called.

Comment: Because I want to track whether the function is called or not, or maybe the condition is true or false !